# Dimension as a real manifold vs dimension as a real variety.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth $\mathbb{R}$ irreducible algebraic set, where the closed sets zero sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of real polynomials.

I am trying to understand why dimension of $X$ as a manifold equals 
the dimension defined topologically (given as the length of a maximal chain of irreducible algebraic sets).

Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent space $T_PX$ of a differential manifold $X$ at a point $P$ is isomorphic to the space of (real) linear derivation of the ring of germs of $X$ at $P$.

On the other hand the Zariski tangent space $T_PX$ of $X$ at a point $P$ is isomorphic to the space of $\mathbb{R}$-linear derivation of $X$ at $P$.

From all this:
\begin{equation}
\forall P\in X,\,\dim X=\dim_{\mathbb{R}}T_PX=\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\mathfrak{m}_{P\displaystyle/\mathfrak{m}_P^2}=\dim_{Krull}\mathcal{O}_{X,P}=\dim_{Krull}X;
\end{equation}
where $(\mathcal{O}_{X,P},\mathfrak{m}_P)$ is the local ring of germs of regular functions on $X$ at $P$.

**Remark:** This reasoning holds on complex numbers field.

**A consequence.** If $X$ is a semisimple, complex Lie group, then its Lie algebra $T_{1_X}X$ is its Lie algebra as semisimple, complex algebraic group.